# Why is column C skipped when VBA code runs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a worksheet change event script to copy a range of cells to a new area on the sheet when the 'Status' column is changed to "Complete". While testing I have noticed that column C is being skipped when the script runs as if it does not exist.

Putting a watch on the variable shows that the value of B is present until cleared, then on the next iteration of the 'For Each' loop the value of the variable is from column D. I have tried to create a new workbook and add the code to a fresh sheet and the same thing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
    Dim dlr As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim nr As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim mAValue As Variant
    Dim mARange As Range
    Dim wsIW As Worksheet
    Set wsIW = Worksheets("IW Phase")
 
    If Target.Column = 14 And Target.Row > 12 Then ' 14 means Column N, modify it as per your need
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        r = Target.Row
        lr = 499
        nr = 500
        dlr = wsIW.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       
        Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult
        Dim cRange As Range
        Set cRange = wsIW.Range("B" & r & ":O" & r)
 
        If Target.Value = "Review complete, actions closed" Then
            Ans = MsgBox("Action will be moved to the Closed Actions area." & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "                        Are you sure?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Confirm Action Close")
            If Ans = vbYes Then
            wsIW.Cells(dlr, 42).Value = Date
                For Each cell In cRange
                    If cell.MergeCells Then
                        mAValue = cell.MergeArea.Value
                        Set mARange = cell.MergeArea
                        wsIW.Cells(dlr, cell.Column).Offset(0, 26).Value = mAValue
                        mARange.UnMerge
                        cell.Delete xlShiftUp
                        Set mARange = mARange.Resize(mARange.Rows.Count)
                        mARange.Merge
                        mARange.Cells(1, 1).Value = mAValue
                    Else:
                        wsIW.Cells(dlr, cell.Column).Offset(0, 26).Value = cell.Value
                        cell.Delete xlShiftUp
                    End If
                Next cell
            Else: Target.Value = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
 
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Re-enable screen updating
        wsIW.Range("B" & lr & ":O" & lr).Copy wsIW.Range("B" & nr & ":O" & nr)
 
    End If
 
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Always re-enable events
End Sub
```

I have tried fixing the issue but I actually don't know what/why it is happening. I have tried to work around by hiding column C but this presents a whole host of issues and is generally not an good solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: FYI in a worksheet code module you can use `Me` to refer to the worksheet itself.  No need for `wsIW`

Comment: I wouldn't delete any cells from the range until you're done processing, then just call `cRange.Delete xlShiftUp`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the `cell.Delete xlShiftUp` - it's not a good idea to delete parts of a range you're looping over - the result can be hard to predict.

Eg:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = [B4:F4]
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Debug.Print c.Address, rng.Address
        c.Delete xlShiftUp
    Next c
    'rng.Delete xlShiftUp   'do this instead
End Sub
```

Result:

```txt
$B$4          $B$4:$F$4
$D$4          $C$4:$F$4  '<< no C !
$E$4          $C$4:$F$4
$F$4          $C$4:$F$4
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty novice with this so still not too sure what was going wrong. I took the delete cells out and added delete range after the loop and it works.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please flag as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  This helps anyone coming along later with a similar question to see there's a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this method can find some explanation (but not the expected one)

```
Sub celldel()

Set rang = Range("d24:k24")
For i = 1 To rang.Cells.Count
Debug.Print rang.Cells(i).Address, rang.Address
rang.Cells(i).Delete xlShiftUp
Next i


End Sub
```

---

```
$D$24         $D$24:$K$24
$F$24         $E$24:$K$24
$G$24         $E$24:$K$24
$H$24         $E$24:$K$24
$I$24         $E$24:$K$24
$J$24         $E$24:$K$24
$K$24         $E$24:$K$24
$F$25         $E$24:$J$24
```

According to this, the first and last cell deletion reduct the range on the corresponding end.